# UITextContentType creditCardNumber is not working

Tags: swift, credit-card

We attempted to set the contentType of UITextField to suggest hint about the added credit card number. Following code has been used :-

```
txtField.returnKeyType = .done

txtField.placeholder = "Card Number"

txtField.keyboardType = .default

txtField.textContentType = .creditCardNumber
```

We are not getting the expected suggestions about credit card no.
We have added one credit card in Account’s Payment & Shipping section.
Please help if I am missing something here.

Comment: From the documentation, setting `textContentType` doesn't *guarantee* anything. It's merely a suggestion. Perhaps try adding more text fields with other parts of the credit card (name, export date, CVV etc) as content type, to give more hints to the system.

Comment: Did you try to make `keyboardType` `numberPad`?

Comment: @lazarevzubov I already try it.

Comment: @Sweeper Using same also, But not work for text fields related to card